# OpenLayers Get Column Value Of Currently Selected Feature Having JSON Data Source

Tags: openlayers, select, json

I have a service that return data in json format as the following snippet:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features":[{"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "sheet_no": "NF4011D", "geometry": {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[57.25,21],[57,21],[57,21.25],[57,21.5],[57.25,21.5],[57.5,21.5],[57.5,21.25],[57.5,21],[57.25,21]]]]}}, ...
```

All I want is to get the sheet_no of the selected feature, example: NF4011D

I added the selection method as follows:

```
selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
    layers:[indexLayer]
}); 
navMap.addInteraction(selectClick);
```

I added also the click event to this layer as follows:

```
selectClick.on('select', function(e) 
{
      //I tried
      var x = e.element.get('sheet_no');// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
      //also
      var features = selectClick.getFeatures();
      var feature = features.item(0); 
      var no = feature.get('sheet_no');  //results in undefined
      //also
      var name = features[0].attributes.id // attributes not defined
      //and others  
      //also
      var sheets = selectedFeatures.getArray().map(function(feature) 
        {
            return feature.get('sheet_no');
        });

        if (sheets.length > 0) 
        {
            console.log("names: "+sheets); //returns nothing
        }
});
```

I have tried for a day almost every solution that is market as correct in stackoverflow but unfortunately I could never get one working:

This this question has been there for a while and got answered. But I think that there is something in my json file that is different.
Please help

Comment: try `e.selected[0].get('sheet_no')`

Comment: that results in undefined

Comment: It's because your json isn't a standard geojson which should look like `{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features":[{"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "sheet_no": "NF4011D" }, "geometry": {`  Some pre-processing will be needed if you are using `ol.format.GeoJSON`

Comment: Oh my god, that just solved my problem. I just added the properties column in my query with the value sheet_no.

Comment: how to mark that as correct answer? Should I add the answer myself?

Comment: In this case, how to get the "id" which is not in the properties considering the standard json?

Comment: id is part of the geojson standard so you can use `getId()`

Comment: Greate, this was very helpful. Thank you Mr. Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON should use a properties collection for non-standard properties to comply with the GeoJSON standard:

```
  { "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "properties": { "sheet_no": "NF4011D" },
      "geometry": {
        "type":"MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [[[[57.25,21],[57,21],[57,21.25],[57,21.5],[57.25,21.5],[57.5,21.5],[57.5,21.25],[57.5,21],[57.25,21]]]]
      }
    },
    ... ]
  }
```

Comment: That is correct. Thank you Mr. Mike